# importing tensorflow or keras showing 500 server error in google cloud

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, keras, google-cloud-platform

I have a simple Flask app which uses tensorflow and keras. The only thing this app does is,

1. Get an API request
2. Perform some operations using keras
3. Return a response

The keras model is pre-trained. This works perfectly on local server. When I deploy the app in Google Cloud, importing tensorflow and keras takes long time and the server returns **"Error: Server Error. The server encountered an error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds."**

main.py:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS
import base64
import io
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import resize
from matplotlib import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

# import tensorflow as tf
# from keras.models import load_model
# import keras.backend as k
# from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)

# sess = tf.Session()
# graph = tf.get_default_graph()

# K.tensorflow_backend.set_session(sess)
# model = load_model('./model.h5')

@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'
    # global sess
    # global graph
    # with graph.as_default():
    #     K.tensorflow_backend.set_session(sess)
    #     data = request.get_json()
    #     ### DO SOME WORK HERE ###
    #     return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Whenever I try to uncomment one of the tensorflow/keras imports, it shows the server error.

requirements.txt

```
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.8
Keras==2.3.1
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.0
matplotlib==3.2.1
numpy==1.18.2
scikit-image==0.16.2
tensorflow==1.13.1
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: python37
instance_class: F4
```

Is there anything I am missing? I am new to google cloud deployment.

Comment: Is there anything in the logs for your function?

Comment: Nothing related to the server error. I get a warning though, `OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k`. which I think also not related.

Comment: Are you still getting the Server Error ?